# ¿Cuál es la relación entre el vino de manzanilla y la infusión de manzanilla?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, etimología

Siempre me he preguntado por la razón por la que estos dos términos parecen coincidir, hasta el punto de que "Me he tomado un vaso de manzanilla" resulta completamente ambiguo.

Answer (score 4):

La etimología de la manzanilla es discutida. El correspondiente artículo de [wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manzanilla_%28vino%29) describe cuatro teorías. La etimología más aceptada afirma que el nombre de este vino se deriva de la similitud entre su fragancia y la planta aromática del mismo nombre. Las otras tres etimologías propuestas sugieren una relación con una localidad del mismo nombre en Huelva, con una clase de vid hoy desaparecida, o con el olor de la manzana.

En cuanto a la ambigüedad: sí que es posible, pero el contexto suele hacer innecesaria la distinción.

Comment: No me parece tan sencillo diferenciar. Si vas a un bar y pides una manzanilla, en algunos lugares te pondrán una infusión y en otros, un vino. Es fácil llevarse a equívoco.

Comment: En Cuba cuando dices manzanilla, entederan la infusion, que nosotros mas bien decimos `té`

Comment: No niego la ambigüedad. Lo que afirmo es que no es frecuente. Al menos en el norte de España, cuando pides una manzanilla te ponen una infusión porque es raro que tengan vino de Manzanilla. En Andalucía, imagino sucederá lo contrario, si pides manzanilla seguramente te pondrán el vino, especialmente si son las ferias :) . Espero que algún sevillano nos saque de dudas.

Comment: Yo serviría una infusión. Para quien haya descubierto este vino, como es mi caso: Según la RAE *Infusión de esta flor, que se usa mucho como estomacal, antiespasmódica y febrífuga.* contra *Vino blanco que se hace en Sanlúcar de Barrameda y en otros lugares de Andalucía.*. Aquí en Cataluña si digo `manzanilla` y también porque su otro nombre `camomila` es casi igual en catalán (camamilla) entenderían la infusión.

Answer (score 1):

En Andalucía, si tienes pinta de extranjero y pides una manzanilla, te responden "No tengo encendida la máquina de agua caliente". Yo siempre tengo que añadir: "...pero sin cucharilla ni azúcar" para que me entiendan. La ambigüedad, de hecho, es total. Salvo si estás en una carpa de la Feria, claro.